# How do I generate a polychoric correlation matrix in R-psych

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a polychoric correlation matrix in R-psych for a 227 x 6 data table which I have called nepr. Importing the data from an excel spreadsheet and entering the code:

```
nepr=as.data.frame(nepr)
attach(nepr)
library(psych)
out=polychoric(nepr)
neprpoly=out$rho
print(neprpoly,digits=2)
```

generates the following error message:

```
>Error in if (any(lower > upper)) stop("lower>upper integration 
limits"): missing value where   TRUE/FALSE needed
>In addition: warning messages:
>1. In polychoric(nepr): The items do not have an equal number 
of response alternatives, global set to FALSE.
>2. In qnorm(cumsum(rsum)[-length(rsum)]): NaNs produced
```

I was expecting the code which I entered to produce a polychoric correlation matrix based on the dataframe nepr and don't know how to interpret/ act on the error messages which I have received.

Can anyone suggest what changes I need to make to the code to address the error messages?

A sample of the dataset is as follows:

```
structure(list(Balance = c(4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1), Earth = c(4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5), Plants = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4), Modify = c(2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Growth = 
c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2), 
Mankind = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA,20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data consists of inputs of Likert scale rankings (ranked 1-5) to the items 'Balance', 'Earth', 'Plants', 'Modify', 'Growth', and 'Mankind'. There are no missing values in any cells of the 227 row x 6 item matrix; Balance, Plants, & Growth all contain the values 1-5; Earth contains the values 2-5 (no ranking of 1 recorded); Mankind contains the values 1-4 (no ranking of 5 recorded). When I ran the original data set (before reversing the valence of the last 3 columns) I was able to get a polychoric matrix with no problems even though the data contained the Earth data as it appears in the nepr data set. I assume that it is not uncommon to have similar data sets from surveys where variables do not necessarily contain the full range of response values.

Comment: Hi Mark, it’s difficult for us to help much without a [mre] that lets us run your code and reproduce / investigate the error. In this case, we would need a sample of your `nepr` dataset. To share this, run `dput(head(nepr, 10))` in R, then [edit] your post to paste in the result. Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) for more info on providing MREs for R questions.

Comment: The data is necessary to be certain, but the first error message indicates that the variables do not have an equal number of response values, e.g. Agree, Neutral, Disagree would be 3 response values. The second message suggests there may be missing values. Working through the examples on the manual page `?polychoric` may be helpful.